# Connection between svg elements

Tags: svg, raphael, jquery-svg

Is there a way to connect 2 elements in svg to achieve a "flow chart" like diagram? I have 2 boxes, an arrow between them, and I would like that if I drag one box, the arrow stays connected to the box.

I've founded that there is a [spec](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/connector/SVGConnector.html) for this feature in SVG 1.1 but is far from being completed.

I can't find any piece of code or library that does it (and I think it isn't a rare use case), and I would like to be sure that there isn't a proven way of doing it before I start making it myself.

Thanks!

Comment: it's not a feature of SVG 1.1, it's a standalone working draft (which means it can and will likely change quite a bit before it's done).

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the Dracula Graph Library which uses Raphael and does exactly what you mean:

http://www.graphdracula.net/

Update: I haven't used jquery-svg before, but I put something small together that may get you going: http://jsfiddle.net/7vJmy/2/

It takes advantage of jquery-ui draggable, but I suspect there's a nicer way to do it using the jquery.svganim.js package that's include with the library - anyway, this is all I have time for now.

Also, if you can in the future, include things like library restrictions in the question so you can get more specific answers from the get go! :) Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm waiting for some response using the jquery-svg plugin that I'm currently using. If nothing else appears I'll accept your answer.